# What constitutes the 'The table before the LORD' in Ezekiel 41:22?

Tags: ezekiel

In Ezekiel 41:21-22,

> "21 The posts of the temple were squared, and the face of the sanctuary; the appearance of the one as the appearance of the other.
>   22 The altar of wood was three cubits high, and the length thereof two cubits; and the corners thereof, and the length thereof, and the walls thereof, were of wood: and he said unto me, This is the table that is before the LORD,"

to what element/s does he refer as the table of the LORD?

Answer (score -1):

It is good to see other Bible traductions to get a clear view of what this passage talks about. The table of the lord, or "Altar" as mentioned in this passage represents the continous presence of the Lord. When His presence is continous we can conclude that nothing escapes His eye. He sees everything and knows everything what is happening in His temple. His presence represents Holiness. His presence is a garantuee that nothing goes wrong but all is in His control. The whole passage of Ezechiel leading to the discription of the temple is an introduction to not only the presence of His Glory but also the extending of His Glory outside the temple area. Nothing happens without a purpose and no purpose stays without results.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange Verheecke, thanks for contributing! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)

Comment: (-1) It would be good to see more engagement with specific texts in this answer, to make it clearer how you are applying hermeneutical principles to arrive at your conclusions.